# Flow condition using CONTAINS doesn't work properly

Tags: visual-workflow, list, contains

I'm working on a flow, and basically I'm trying to compare number values with an "Array". 
when I debug d the flow, the condition fails:

```
DECISION: verificarMesAProbar
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met:
mesAProbarEstaEnListaNumeroFechas
Outcome conditions:
{!listaNumeroMeses} ([12,1,2,3,4,5,6]) Contains {!temp_NumeroFechaAVerificar} (2)
```

I think is clear that 2 (**temp_NumeroFechaAVerificar**) is in the List (**listaNumeroMeses**).

Both, the list and the variable **temp_NumeroFechaAVerificar** are typed like Number (Collection and single variables).

This happends in the second iteration. the first one works just fine.

```
DECISION: verificarMesAProbar
Outcome executed: mesAProbarEstaEnListaNumeroFechas
Outcome conditions:
{!listaNumeroMeses} ([12,1,2,3,4,5,6]) Contains {!temp_NumeroFechaAVerificar} (12)
```