# Invocable Apex to compare 2 collections and get unique elements

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

We have a flow that loops through 2 objects (User & Email message) and stores its email addresses in 2 collections (Co11 and col2). I want to compare 2 collections and get unique elements before i send out an email to unique email addresses. I tried to loop through and use a decision outcome to see if the col1 contains in col2 however there seems to be a limitation on CONTAINS function. I looked up [This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308362/flow-condition-using-contains-doesnt-work-properly)
but doesn't seem to find any solution. Is there any way we can compare 2 collections from flow and get unique elements without writing APEX? If not, how do i compare 2 input collections in apex and pass it  back to flow from apex?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325671&type=1), CONTAINS only compares strings so cannot be used to compare collections.

Take a look at (and perhaps vote for) [this idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdoYTUAZ/please-add-a-remove-common-flow-operators-in-assignment-elements) and note the references to unofficialsf.com where you will find pre-build [List actions for Flows](https://unofficialsf.com/list-actions-for-flow/) that you can incorporate into your solution instead of writing the code yourself.